# Creating an alternative to bash for Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, command-line, osx-snow-leopard

Is a shell a normal CLI application, or is it different from an application that accepts input from standard input, and outputs the result on standard output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell reads standard input, writes to standard output/error as appropriate, and executes other programs.  If you are interested in what it takes to write one, I would recommend reading [*"UNIX Systems Programming"* by Kay Robbins and Steve Robbins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130424110).  I haven't read this version, the original copy was named *"Practical UNIX Programming"*.  It does contain sections devoted to process management that include writing a very basic shell.  If you haven't read [*"Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment"* by Stevens](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321525949), then I would suggest reading it as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, a shell just reads from stdin and outputs to stdout. Obviously it *does* do more than that, but that's the basics.